# plot using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Panel data models}
\framesubtitle{Fixed effects}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=.8,
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
\addplot [
    domain=0:30, 
    samples=20, 
    color=red,
]
{100+8*x};

    \addplot [
    domain=0:30, 
    samples=20, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {130+8*x};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Basically, I would like to plot a graph containing three or more lines. They have the same slope but different intercept. I cannot see how I can have the y-axis starting from 0. Differently it seems that the red one starts from the origin. Moreover, I would like to put a label close to each line explaining it (something like line 1, line 2). I do not need a cumulative legend (which I could obtain with `\addlegendentry{}` as far as I know. Currently the above is what I was able to obtain so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you wanting a `node`, something like `\addplot [
    domain=0:30, 
    samples=20, 
    color=red,
]
{100+8*x} node {text};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Panel data models}
\framesubtitle{Fixed effects}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=.8,
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 200,
]
% Plot 1
\addplot [
    domain=0:30, 
    samples=20, 
    color=red,
    ]
    {100+8*x};
\addlegendentry[]{Plot 1}
% Plot 2
\addplot [
    domain=0:30, 
    samples=20, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {130+8*x};
\addlegendentry[]{Plot 2}    
%    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- Have you had a look in the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)?
- Just look for `legend` (4.9.4 Legends)...
- The other question is solved with `ymin` (4.14 Specifying the Plotted Range).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, I know that I could use \addlegendentry[]{Plot 1}. The point is that I would like a label close to each of the lines. Consider like a text box without delimiting lines. Is this possible?

Comment: Surely, I explained my point badly in my question. I know how to use addlegendentry, but this is not what I want. See my comment above.

Comment: @Dario I didn't read your question careful enough. I am offline for the rest of the week. Look for `annotation` in the manual and/or hope for others to help :).

Comment: Thanks Manuel. I will have a look at 'annotation'. Thanks again

Comment: @Dario Any maybe make your question clearer. For example by using bullet points.